# Instant App - Version Code Should Be Less Than Installable App

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm working on an Android app that is published on Play Store for years and its current published version code is around 3000. Meaning that all version codes less than 3000 have already been uploaded to play store.

Now as a proof of concept, I'm working on an instant app experience. As per [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle#version-codes) it's possible to develop a separate app for instant experience as long as it has the same applicationId as the installable app and lower version code.

So I developed a separate application for the instant experience, used the same applicationId and signing config as the installable app and set the versionCode to 1 so that it's less than the installable app. I generated the app bundle for instant app and tried uploading it to Play Store Test track. I'm now getting an error that the `Version code 1 has already been used. Try another version code.`

I'm really confused because the documentation explicitly mentioned the instant app should have a less versionCode of the installable app.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Same issue here, ever figure it out?

Comment: Your instant app needs to have a version code that is less than your full app but also not being used before. So let's say your full app is at 3000. You can have your instant app to be 3001 and then jump your full app to 9000. This gives your instant app a 6000 version number room and also 3001 is not used.

Comment: Yes, I think this is what we ended up landing on. Thank you!